# Query creation from method name not working. Trying to filter pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to filter my returned paginated dataset by an isPrivate boolean column on my table. I believe that I should be able to create query by adding the following method name.

I have been reading the spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.create-instances.java-config), I double checked that I have the @EnableJpaRepositories("//Project here") annotation on my database config. I can call findall and it works as expected.

```
public interface AnnouncementRepository extends JpaRepository<Announcement, Long> {
    Page<Announcement> findByisPrivate(boolean isPrivate, Pageable page);
}
```

Error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'announcementResource' defined in file
```

Comment: Okay, first check if you'r `Pageable` import is from spring package (`org.springframework.data.domain`). If yes, change it, if it doesn't work then you've got to give us more. Start with full stack-trace, `Announcement` entity class), and `spring-data-jpa` version that you're using.

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** instead of snippet.

Answer (score 0):

`isPrivate` is likely not the properties name but its getter, which would make `private` its name.
Therefore, the query method should be named `findByPrivate`.

If the property is actually named `isPrivate`, i.e. the getter is named `isIsPrivate` or `getIsPrivate` the method name should be `findByIsPrivate`.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that I should use the getter. That worked! Thank you.